# basic conditional probability proof

Tags: probability, proof-writing

I having trouble with the following proof:
$$P((A \cap B) \mid B) = P(A\mid B).$$

I get that $P(A\mid B) = P(A \cap B) / P (B)$, but I am unsure of how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just carefully apply the definition of $P(A\cap B\mid B)$ to obtain an expression for $P(A\cap B\mid B)$. Hint: for a set $B$, $B\cap B = B$.